# What state is support for PCI-Express hotplug in?

Tags: motherboard, pci-express, hotplug

When I first started reading about PCI-Express a decade ago I was excited about the possibility of hotplug support, but when I got my first motherboards with PCI-Express and tried it out, the system hung, and a quick trip around Google told me that hotplug wasn't generally supported on consumer-grade hardware. Since then I haven't really dared trying again for potential risk of damaging my hardware.

Is this still true today? Do consumer-grade motherboards still not support PCI-Express hotplug in general? Assuming I don't do stupid things like inserting cards at an angle, could I damage the hardware simply by testing to see what would happen (and if so, seeing as how the slot interface is designed with hot-plug in mind with longer ground leads and whatnot, why)?

Comment: My sample size is not very large (that's why I posting as a comment) but I have yet to see a consumer grade product that stated that it supports hot plugging (but I have not been looking very hard).